# How do I solve an advance filter problem, using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I would like to know a solution which can help me generate a MySQL query to fetch data as I want from a single data base table.

```
Table name: Rates 
Columns: id, date, weekday, costA, costB, costC, sellA, sellB, sellC
SAMPLE TABLE DATA
=================

id | date    | weekday | costA | costB | costC | sellA | sellB | sellC
----------------------------------------------------------------------
01  2010/6/1     TUE      120     135     140     150     165    180
02  2010/6/2     WED      120     135     140     150     165    180
03  2010/6/3     THU      120     135     140     150     165    180
04  2010/6/4     FRI      120     135     140     150     165    180
05  2010/6/5     SAT      120     135     140     150     165    180
06  2010/6/6     SUN      120     135     140     150     165    180
07  2010/6/7     MON      120     135     140     150     165    180
...
16  2010/6/16    WED      150     140     140     200     220    230
17  2010/6/17    THU      150     140     140     200     220    230
18  2010/6/18    FRI      150     140     140     200     220    230
19  2010/6/19    SAT      150     140     140     200     220    230
20  2010/6/20    SUN      150     140     140     200     220    230
21  2010/6/21    MON      150     140     140     200     220    230
22  2010/6/22    TUE      150     140     140     200     220    230
```

The query I want to do with this table is that, I want to get the starting date of each cost and sell column and the last date of the price changed. Which I did manage to do it with the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM rates ID IN(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM `rates` GROUP BY costA,costB,costC,sellA,sellB,sellC) OR ID IN(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `rates` GROUP BY costA,costB,costC,sellA,sellB,sellC)
```

How ever the problem I have to tackle is, if in case for example, every wednesday and on every friday has two different price from 2010/06/01 to 2010/06/16. So how do I generate a query which can give me a total summary by weekdays as explained below.

```
id | date    | weekday | costA | costB | costC | sellA | sellB | sellC
----------------------------------------------------------------------
01  2010/6/1     TUE      120     135     140     150     165    180
02  2010/6/2     WED      100     100     100     110     120    130
03  2010/6/3     THU      120     135     140     150     165    180
04  2010/6/4     FRI      140     150     160     150     175    180
05  2010/6/5     SAT      120     135     140     150     165    180
06  2010/6/6     SUN      120     135     140     150     165    180
07  2010/6/7     MON      120     135     140     150     165    180
...
16  2010/6/16    WED      100     100     100     110     120    130
17  2010/6/17    THU      150     140     140     200     220    230
18  2010/6/18    FRI      150     140     140     200     220    230
19  2010/6/19    SAT      150     140     140     200     220    230
20  2010/6/20    SUN      150     140     140     200     220    230
21  2010/6/21    MON      150     140     140     200     220    230
22  2010/6/22    TUE      150     140     140     200     220    230
```

From the above table, the report I need to generate should be something similar to the one below.

```
id | date    | weekday | costA | costB | costC | sellA | sellB | sellC
----------------------------------------------------------------------
01  2010/6/1     TUE      120     135     140     150     165    180
02  2010/6/2     WED      100     100     100     110     120    130
03  2010/6/3     THU      120     135     140     150     165    180
04  2010/6/4     FRI      140     150     160     150     175    180
05  2010/6/5     SAT      120     135     140     150     165    180
15  2010/6/15    TUE      120     135     140     150     165    180
16  2010/6/16    WED      100     100     100     110     120    130
17  2010/6/17    THU      150     140     140     200     220    230
22  2010/6/22    TUE      150     140     140     200     220    230
```

Where it is read from the above table as
2010/06/01 to 2010/06/16 rates are:

```
WEEKDAY|  costA | costB | costC | sellA | sellB | sellC
  SAT     120     135     140     150     165    180 
  SUN     120     135     140     150     165    180
  MON     120     135     140     150     165    180
  TUE     120     135     140     150     165    180
  WED     100     100     100     110     120    130
  THU     120     135     140     150     165    180
  FRI     140     150     160     150     175    180
```

and from 2010/06/17 to 2010/06/22

```
WEEKDAY|  costA | costB | costC | sellA | sellB | sellC
  SAT     150     140     140     200     220    230 
  SUN     150     140     140     200     220    230
  MON     150     140     140     200     220    230
  TUE     150     140     140     200     220    230
  WED     150     140     140     200     220    230
  THU     150     140     140     200     220    230
  FRI     150     140     140     200     220    230
```

I hope there will be a solution to tackle this problem. In short, what i am trying to do here is to generate a periodic table of rates, where it will tell the cost/sell price details based on weekdays and grouped into dynamic date periods telling the start and end date of every similar week.

Comment: `a query which can give me a total summary by weekdays` - I fail to see how your report example is a summary by weekdays. Care to explain further?

Comment: If you look at the bottom two tables, with prices for each weekdays within a date period (date periods depends on every change of price on a date). the  result I want to output from a query should be as like the bottom two tables.Simply to say, I want to get a result from the first table which can show prices based to weekdays and their applicable date period. something like a rate card produced based on the daily prices entered. I hope u got my idea clear. I can explain more if you need. thanks Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
select weekday,costA,costB,costC,sellA,sellB,sellC, min(date) from_dt, max(date) to_dt
from rates 
group by weekday,costA,costB,costC,sellA,sellB,sellC
```